# insert to sql db (no duplicate)

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates

i've problem with inserting data to my db. i wanna know how can i add only data which not already in the table??

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.Posta
    (
        DrzavaID,
        PostnaStevilka,
        Naziv,
        record_dt_modified,
        record_modifier_id,
        record_dt_created,
        record_creator_id
    )

    select 
        d.DrzavaID,
        p.PostnaSt, 
        concat(CONCAT(p.Provinca,+' - '+p.Okrozje),+' - '+p.Mesto),
        @record_dt_modified,
        @record_modifier_id,
        @record_dt_modified,
        @record_modifier_id
    FROM mmdb_kopijaSI.dbo.Drzava d,#PostaT p
    WHERE d.Kratica='TR';
```

---

```
alter PROCEDURE addPosta 
AS
BEGIN
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','ALADA?(KARSANTI)','AKÖREN',1720 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','ALADA?(KARSANTI)','KARSANTI',1720 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','ALADA?(KARSANTI)','MERKEZKÖYLER',1720 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','B?RKENT',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','BÜYÜKMANGIT',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','CEYHAN',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','DORUK',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','EMEK',1940 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','HAMD?LL?',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','KÖSREL?',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','KURTKULA?I',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','KURTPINAR',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','MERC?MEK',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','MERKEZKÖYLER',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','MUSTAFABEYL?',1920 );
insert into #PostaT values( 'ADANA','CEYHAN','NAMIKKEMAL',1950 );
```

.
..
...to 10000 inserts

```
CREATE TABLE #PostaT
    (
        Provinca varchar(20),
        Okrozje varchar(20),
        Mesto varchar(20),
        PostnaSt int
    )

    exec [PosteZaPoseg];
```

i fill my table with procedure with about 10000 items. I wanna fill the table only with data from Procedure [PosteZaPoseg] which is not in table

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer may depend on the product used.)

Answer (score 0):

You must check data on your table

Try This

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')
        INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
    ELSE
        UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
```

Comment: i've got 10000 items in dbo.posta. how can i check all values??

Comment: maybe you can use Merge  its so faster.

Comment: can i check some like that: IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1=(select column1 from table2 ))

Because i get an error:
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Slovenian_CI_AS" and "Turkish_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: please try to change table collation

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it like this:

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.Posta
       (DrzavaID
       , PostnaStevilka
       , Naziv
       , record_dt_modified
       , record_modifier_id
       , record_dt_created
       , record_creator_id
        )
SELECT  d.DrzavaID
      , p.PostnaSt
      , CONCAT(CONCAT(p.Provinca, +' - ' + p.Okrozje), +' - ' + p.Mesto)
      , @record_dt_modified
      , @record_modifier_id
      , @record_dt_modified
      , @record_modifier_id
FROM    mmdb_kopijaSI.dbo.Drzava d
      , #PostaT p
LEFT JOIN   dbo.Posta q
    ON      q.keyfld  = p.keyfld
WHERE   d.Kratica = 'TR'
    AND q.keyfld IS NULL;
```

I am assuming you have a unique key on the Posta and #Posta tables (I took the fake name `keyfld` for it).

Furthermore, are you aware that you are creating a carthesian product as you are not directly linking the Drzava table to the #PostaT table?